# Weston—run program on desktop start

Tags: wayland, autostart

I have successfully installed wayland/weston on my system. I would like to start a program (chromium) whenever weston starts. Right now:

```
weston-lauch
```

starts the desktop, from there I can start a terminal and type `chromium`, what starts chromium. But is it possible to start chromium automatically, just when the desktop is loaded? If so, how? All I can find is how to add a item to the launcher panel…

Comment: Does weston support XDG-autostart currently?

Comment: I don't know yet. Is there a simple way to check?

Answer (score 0):

Since version 9.0.91 ([commit](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/wayland/weston/-/commit/60855b1569ef5b57de8ecc06b8507046dfb57ced)), Weston supports starting an application by adding an `[autolaunch]` section in `weston.ini`.

```
[autolaunch]
path=/usr/bin/firefox
```

See [man weston.ini](https://man.archlinux.org/man/weston.ini.5.en#AUTOLAUNCH_SECTION)

The XDG autostart spec is not (yet?) implemented (see [official repository](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/search?group_id=1158&project_id=120&repository_ref=main&scope=blobs&search=autostart)).