# Start a Qt/wayland application on top of weston on startup

Tags: systemd, startup, init-script, qt, wayland

I would like to launch a Qt application on start up. The application uses some of the features from weston/wayland desktop, so it should be launched on top of weston, right after weston is started. Normally, I work with SSH to connect to the target platform and launch the application using following commands:

```
systemctl stop weston
weston --tty=1
./QtApp
```

If I do not kill the weston and do not start it with a TTY, I get the following error:

```
Failed to create display
```

What I have tried to do is to set up a start up script and integrate it into the systemd:

```
[Unit]
Description = Onyx Service
After = weston.service
Type = forking

[Service]
ExecStart = /bin/bash /opt/onyx-start

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

However, as you can guess, this does not work. I need to manage to start an application on an existing weston instance that is not started with a TTY option.

Comment: Related : [Weston—run program on desktop start](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/495243/309969)

Answer (score 5):

Typically it's not about starting Weston on a specific tty, but about having the environment variables set which will route you to the proper instances of Wayland and Weston. These variables are such as `WAYLAND_DISPLAY` and even `DISPLAY` for applications that need XWayland.

You can typically get the proper environment you need by sourcing a file such as `/etc/profile.d/weston.sh` (or `wayland_env.sh` in some cases.) This is typically done for you when you log in to a shell, but systemd jobs do not launch a shell, so they don't get these variables set.

Maybe try something like this in `onyx-start`:

```
#!/bin/sh
. /etc/profile.d/weston.sh
exec /path/to/QtApp
```

The service unit you have should work with that.

(If it still doesn't work, please list more details about your environment, such as the Linux distribution you're using, contents of `weston.service`, output of `systemctl status weston.service`, contents of `weston.sh` or `wayland_env.sh` and wether starting QtApp works through SSH without launching a new Weston, perhaps after sourcing the environment profile file, if for any reason those variables aren't being set on those connections.)

Comment: This is awesome. Worked! In my case the file was ``/etc/profile.d/weston.sh``. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: That's great @mozcelikors! I updated the answer to refer to `weston.sh` instead. Really glad this solved it for you!

Comment: I think I spoke too soon and misjudged it. weston.sh only creates XDG_RUNTIME_DIR. This unfortunately did not help running an app on weston. I might have started the daemon with ``weston --tty=1`` when I had success.

Comment: Hmmm ok no worries... Keep looking (if you have time) and update the question with more details, I'll keep trying to help you.

Comment: When I have more details, I'll add. Thanks still.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer of @filbranden, `/etc/profile.d/weston.sh` or `wayland_env.sh` is no longer distributed, so what worked for me was the following script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
weston &
sleep 5s # could be less
export WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0
export DISPLAY=:1
exec /path/to/myapp
```

Comment: Do you know how to get rid of that sleep? I have been investigating that but not been successful finding a working solution yet.

Comment: So, my script was a login script that you could select on the login page and had to start weston. But maybe if you get it started with a service then you don't have to start weston in the script, and thus get rid of the sleep?

Comment: Unfortunaley weston service does not notify.

Comment: Weston can notify with `/usr/bin/weston --modules=systemd-notify.so`. I don't know how to leverage this yet.